# Parameterized remote job is triggered but console says failure

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

Parameterized remote job is triggered successfully
However, console says it has failed

```
Started by user XXX
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
[pipeline] node
Running on Ubuntu in /home/set/jenkins/workspace/android_monkey_builder_pipeline
[pipeline] {
[pipeline] stage
[pipeline] { (Building apk)
[pipeline] script
[pipeline] {
[pipeline] triggerRemoteJob
################################################################################################################
 Parameterized Remote Trigger Configuration:
 - job: https://jenkins.mycompanycorp.com/view/Android%20mycompany%20CI/job/jp.mother.mycompany.android_mycompany-android_C_beta_for_monkey 
 - remoteJenkinsName: mycompanyJenkinsForEveryone
 - auth: 'Token Authentication' as user 'XXX'
 - parameters: [BRANCH=release_9.0]
 - blockBuildUntilComplete: true
 - connectionRetryLimit: 5
################################################################################################################
Triggering parameterized remote job 'https://jenkins.mycompanycorp.com/view/Android%20mycompany%20CI/job/jp.mother.mycompany.android_mycompany-android_C_beta_for_monkey'
 Using job-level defined 'Token Authentication' as user 'XXX'
Triggering remote job now.
CSRF protection is disabled on the remote server.
Connection to remote server failed , waiting for to retry - 10 seconds until next attempt. URL: https://jenkins.mycompanycorp.com/view/Android%20mycompany%20CI/job/jp.mother.mycompany.android_mycompany-android_C_beta_for_monkey/buildWithParameters, parameters: BRANCH=master
Retry attempt #1 out of 5
reuse cached crumb: jenkins.mycompanycorp.com
Connection to remote server failed [404], waiting for to retry - 10 seconds until next attempt. URL: https://jenkins.mycompanycorp.com/view/Android%20mycompany%20CI/queue/item/2522124/api/json/, parameters: 
Retry attempt #1 out of 5
Connection to remote server failed [404], waiting for to retry - 10 seconds until next attempt. URL: https://jenkins.mycompanycorp.com/view/Android%20mycompany%20CI/queue/item/2522124/api/json/, parameters: 
Retry attempt #2 out of 5
Connection to remote server failed [404], waiting for to retry - 10 seconds until next attempt. URL: https://jenkins.mycompanycorp.com/view/Android%20mycompany%20CI/queue/item/2522124/api/json/, parameters: 
Retry attempt #3 out of 5
Connection to remote server failed [404], waiting for to retry - 10 seconds until next attempt. URL: https://jenkins.mycompanycorp.com/view/Android%20mycompany%20CI/queue/item/2522124/api/json/, parameters: 
Retry attempt #4 out of 5
Connection to remote server failed [404], waiting for to retry - 10 seconds until next attempt. URL: https://jenkins.mycompanycorp.com/view/Android%20mycompany%20CI/queue/item/2522124/api/json/, parameters: 
Retry attempt #5 out of 5
ERROR: Remote build failed with 'ExceedRetryLimitException' for the following reason: 'Max number of connection retries have been exeeded.'.
[pipeline] }
[pipeline] // script
[pipeline] }
[pipeline] // stage
[pipeline] }
[pipeline] // node
[pipeline] End of pipeline
ERROR: ExceedRetryLimitException: Max number of connection retries have been exeeded.
Finished: FAILURE
```

I cannot connect to causing 404. Is this a root cause?

> https://jenkins.mycompanycorp.com/view/Android%20mycompany%20CI/queue/item/2522124/api/json/

What I want to do is triggering the build and retrieving artifacts.

Comment: On the remote server, it says "Started by remote host xx.xx.xx.xx"

Answer (score 2):

I guess the problem was from the view name `Android%20mycompany%20CI`.

I changed

```
https://jenkins.mycompanycorp.com/view/Android%20mycompany%20CI/job/jp.mother.mycompany.android_mycompany-android_C_beta_for_monkey
```

to

```
https://jenkins.mycompanycorp.com/job/jp.mother.mycompany.android_mycompany-android_C_beta_for_monkey
```

and it works.

Thank you