# Parameterized remote job via triggerRemoteJob() function using Tokens

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, token

Tried to search a few sites, including [Parameterized remote job is triggered but console says failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53953392/parameterized-remote-job-is-triggered-but-console-says-failure)

I am attempting to migrate a token based job from existing (using curl) method of calling remote job to plugin based call as follows:

**Remote Jenkins Setup**: (myserver:8080) Job: MyPipelineFirstJob

```
Under Job configuration  :  Build Triggers    -->    "Trigger builds remotely (e.g., from scripts)"   -->    Authentication Token    -->    108801
```

**Existing job**: On Local Jenkins:

```
curl -v --silent -X POST http://myserver:8080/job/MyPipelineFirstJob/buildWithParameters --data token=108801 --data RELEASE=9.2 --data ARCHITECTURE=ppc64le --data IP=9.99.999.99
```

**New job** on local Jenkins:
Now, I need to translate the above to use parameterized-remote-trigger-plugin. So Apart from Remote Host, etc, I have chosen the Auth type as follows in the Global configuration: "Parameterized Remote Trigger Configuration"

```
"Enable 'build token root' support" is unchecked -- Do not know what this means
Authentication  -->  Bearer Token Authentication
```

I see a WARNING message as "Address looks good, but a connection could not be established."

I am calling the below funciton to trigger the remote job:

```
def handle = triggerRemoteJob(remoteJenkinsName: 'Perf_Jenkins_Server', job: 'MyPipelineFirstJob/buildByToken/buildWithParameters', auth: "108801", parameters: 'RELEASE=HMC9.2.951.2,ARCHITECTURE=ppc64le,HMC_MACHINE=9.99.999.9998')
```

I have passed the string "108801" based on this site https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/Parameterized-Remote-Trigger/ which says:

```
BearerTokenAuth
    token (optional)
        Type: String
```

**Build Failure**: With the above configuration, when build the job, I get this error:

```
22:07:12  java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.jenkinsci.plugins.ParameterizedRemoteTrigger.pipeline.RemoteBuildPipelineStep.setAuth() expects class org.jenkinsci.plugins.ParameterizedRemoteTrigger.auth2.Auth2 but received class java.lang.String
22:07:12    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.coerce(DescribableModel.java:492)
22:07:12    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.injectSetters(DescribableModel.java:429)
22:07:12    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.instantiate(DescribableModel.java:331)
22:07:12    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeStep(DSL.java:269)
22:07:12    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeMethod(DSL.java:179)
22:07:12    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript.invokeMethod(CpsScript.java:122)
22:07:12    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor493.invoke(Unknown Source)
22:07:12    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
22:07:12    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
```

So, I tried to remove the auth field, and passed it as part of parameters:

```
def handle = triggerRemoteJob(remoteJenkinsName: 'Perf_Jenkins_Server', job: 'MyPipelineFirstJob/buildByToken/buildWithParameters', parameters: 'token="108801",RELEASE="HMC9.2.951.2",ARCHITECTURE=ppc64le,HMC_MACHINE="9.99.999.9998"')
```

Note: I have also attempted to add double quotes around the parameter values. Having made these changes, and attempt to build, I get the following error:

```
22:19:12  ################################################################################################################
22:19:12    Parameterized Remote Trigger Configuration:
22:19:12      - job:                     MyPipelineFirstJob/buildByToken/buildWithParameters 
22:19:12      - remoteJenkinsName:       Perf_Jenkins_Server
22:19:12      - parameters:              [token="108801",RELEASE="HMC9.2.951.2",ARCHITECTURE=ppc64le,HMC_MACHINE="9.99.999.998"]
22:19:12      - blockBuildUntilComplete: true
22:19:12      - connectionRetryLimit:    5
22:19:12      - trustAllCertificates:    false
22:19:12  ################################################################################################################
22:19:12  Connection to remote server failed [404], waiting to retry - 10 seconds until next attempt. URL: http://myserver:8080/job/MyPipelineFirstJob/job/buildByToken/job/buildWithParameters/api/json, parameters: 
22:19:22  Retry attempt #1 out of 5
22:19:22  Connection to remote server failed [404], waiting to retry - 10 seconds until next attempt. URL: http://myserver:8080/job/MyPipelineFirstJob/job/buildByToken/job/buildWithParameters/api/json, parameters: 
22:19:32  Retry attempt #2 out of 5
```

Did you notice the additional "job" word : "buildByToken/job/buildWithParameters" in the above o/p? Not sure why!

Questions:

- Is the Authentication type of "Bearer Token Authentication" the correct option that matches with the requirement of existing method?
- Have I passed the parameters correctly?
- How to overcome the failures seen above?

Comment: First of all, the "job" parameter should be just th ejob name " job: 'MyPipelineFirstJob' ". As long as you get a 404 error, the job name is wrong....

Comment: @PatriceM., Ok, so with your suggestion, the build fails without the 404 error:
      `09:28:48  ERROR: Remote build failed with 'ExceedRetryLimitException' for the following reason: 'Max number of connection retries have been exeeded.'.`

Answer (score 9):

Found the solution: The parameters needs to be separated by a new line. Not a comma or space. So, I added '\n' char between each parameter as shown below and it worked!

```
def handle = triggerRemoteJob(remoteJenkinsName: 'Perf_Jenkins_Server', job: 'MyPipelineFirstJob', parameters: 'token=108801\nRELEASE=9.2.951.2\nARCHITECTURE=x86_64\nMACHINE_IP="9.99.999.998')
```

Ref: The below link has an example that uses "\n" as parameter separator.

https://github.com/jenkinsci/parameterized-remote-trigger-plugin/blob/master/README_PipelineConfiguration.md

Note: The above link refers to Snippet Generator. However, that Generator doesn't support "triggerRemoteJob" yet! May be, I would have solved my issue faster!

Jenkins Version: Jenkins 2.249.1
Parameterized Remote Trigger Plugin Version: 3.1.5.1

Comment: Thanks, @chhatrapati

Comment: Hi, have similar task. I have to execute on a remote Jenkins another task but when i try to use your approach i got errors like `Expected named arguments but got [{and list of parameters}]`. Try different approach and i got `expects class hudson.util.Secret but received class java.lang.String`. Do you have different approach to try. Im using token and user for authentication and if i use it with curl it works but i need to make it work with this plugin. Any suggestions ?